# Error in connect econnrefused response from server

Tags: node.js, express

I got the error from the server with errorno: ECONNREFUSED
My API is working perfectly on my local machine. When I host the code I got a connection error.

If you hit the URL direct you'll get products http://nodenpm.club:3001/products
Here is the API URL which i'm using for accessing the order with products http://nodenpm.club:3002/orders
but when i access this URL using request i got below error

```
{
    "status": false,
    "error": {
        "errno": "ECONNREFUSED",
        "code": "ECONNREFUSED",
        "syscall": "connect",
        "address": "172.17.0.3",
        "port": 3001
    }
}
```

I am using the Ubuntu server for hosting with docker. I have also tried with proxy request but does not work. below is my code for request.

```
const express = require("express");
const request = require('request');
const app = express();

app.get("/orders", (req, res) => {
    var options = {
        url: 'http://nodenpm.club:3001/products',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    };
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
        if (!error) {
            res.status(200).json({
                status: true,
                body: body
            });
        }
    })
});

app.listen(3002, () => {
    console.log('order services listening on http://nodenpm.club:3002');
});
```

my expceted output is below

```
{
    "status": true,
    "products": [
        {
            "_id": "5d5f84afdb78bd0b10e38879",
            "name": "mobile",
            "price": 10000
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think  You have to put the URL into an object for example:
`{url:"http://nodenpm.club:3001/products"}`

Answer (score 0):

You don't include the method of the request. Try:

```
request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error) {
        res.status(200).json({
            status: true,
            body: body
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define method request

```
  request.post(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error) {
        res.status(200).json({
            status: true,
            body: body
        });
    }
})
```

However better use axios